# centre of a group presentation

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

having trouble showing that an element belongs to a centre of a group presentation.

Let $G = \langle x,y,z\mid x^2=y^3=z^3=xyz\rangle$

I have to show that $ a = xyz$ belongs to the centre of $G$. I understand what the centre of a group is (the elements $h \in G$ s.t $hg=gh$ $\forall$ $g \in G$, but my problem is i'm fairly new to working with group presentations and I'm not totally what the elements of G would be. Although I think if i was to make a table using the relations and then compose them with eachother, would that give me the elements of G? Then could i just 'brute force' it?

Comment: This is actually not difficult, because $xyz$ is equal to a power of each generator and (since all elements commute with powers of themselves) it must commute with each generator, and hence it commutes with every element of the group. In general, the group might be infinite, so it would be a hoepless task to try and list all of its elements. In fact this group has order $24$.

Comment: A similar, but infinite, group is $\langle x,y,z; x^7=y^8=z^9=xyz\rangle$ (so it is a hopeless task to list all its elements, but clearly the element $xyz$ is contained in the centre).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: for each generator, show that it commutes with $a$. To do so, use the relations to simplify the expressions.

For example, we first want to show that $xa = ax$. Notice that 
$$
xa = x^2 yz = xyzyz = a yz = ax.
$$